# Error using Discover feature for ES index

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, kibana-4

I have an index called apitestresults. I populate it via spring-data-elasticsearch, version 1.1.2.RELEASE, which is connecting to **elasticsearch 1.4.4**. I then have **Kibana 4.0.1**. set up accessing the elasticsearch instance, this already contains other indices. Using Discover -> Settings -> IndexPattern -> fill out apitestresults, I am getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.28/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest (http://myHostName:5601/index.js?_b=5930:22313)
```

This is also shown on a screenshot here (the blackend part is the hostname)
[image: Image of issue]

Any help is much appreciated

Thanks a lot!